# regular expression for excluding between

Tags: regex

I have the following regular expression:

```
first.*(?<!.*([;,\.]|and).*)second
```

I would like it to match the following:

```
first some word second
```

But not match the following:

```
first . some word second

first ; some word second
```

It is working but it is also excluding the following:

```
blah ; first some word second
```

I only want it to exclude matches if the negative look ahead falls in between the two words. It should not look behind the first word.

Comment: Did any of the answers help you?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use:

```
first\b[^.;]*\bsecond
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you are not using a lookahead, in your pattern, you are using a lookbehind with an unknown width pattern inside. You want to match a string between `a` and `b` excluding `c`, and this is a common scenario for a [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970):

```
first(?:(?!and)[^;,.])*second
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IRyg1E/2). Use word boundaries to match whole words: `\bfirst\b(?:(?!\band\b)[^;,.])*\bsecond\b`.

**Details**

- `first` - a literal substring
- `(?:(?!and)[^;,.])*` - zero or more chars other than `;`, `,` and `.` that do not start an `and` char sequence
- `second` - a literal substring.